# Cloning just a particular directory with hg?

Tags: svn, mercurial, tortoisehg, hgsubversion

I come from a Subversion background, but I am slowly migrating to Mercurial.

When starting on many of my projects, I would setup a development environment that was configured to a particular starting point in developing an app/webapp/program (much like a Maven 2 archetype, but not necessarily Java/Maven).

Later I would **checkout** this archetype/template project out of my svn repo by its particular path; and than **export** the working copy from version control by the repository; so that I could import the working copy back in to another repository without adding the changes that I made to the working copy to the base the template/archetype project.

I've tried doing the same thing in Mercurial, and I've run into a wall since I can't **check out**, *er..um..no*, **clone** a specific path from the hg repository.

If I want to achieve the same sort of functionality using Mercurial, what should I do?
Use tagged branches?  The archetypes/template projects are very different, but I'd like to keep them in the same repository.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **repository** is a much more lightweight concept in Mercurial.  Although you said you would like to avoid it, I would probably create a separate repository in this situation.  In situations where you require a shared history between your repositories, you can use the **[ShareExtension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ShareExtension)**.

Comment: Well I guess I'm gonna have to pay assembla.com more then... :(

Comment: Ahh, yes.  It's unfortunate that hosted sites charge by the repo.  It really goes against the nature of mercurial's lightweight setup.